# AWS Cognito Credentials Provider for IOS - access key and secret key are nil

Tags: ios, objective-c, amazon-simpledb, amazon-cognito, aws-sdk-ios

I am trying to use `AWSCognito` in Objective C to authenticate to an Amazon SimpleDB database. 
I initalize an `AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider` with the identity pool id provided in my Amazon account. The problem is that when I try to get the access key and secret key from the `AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider` object, they are nil.

I initalize the credentials provider likes this:

```
 AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider *credentialsProvider = [AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider credentialsWithRegionType:AWSRegionUSEast1 accountId:ACCOUNT_ID identityPoolId:IDENTITY_POOL_ID unauthRoleArn:UNAUTH_ROLE authRoleArn:AUTH_ROLE];

 AWSServiceConfiguration *configuration = [AWSServiceConfiguration configurationWithRegion:AWSRegionUSEast1 credentialsProvider:credentialsProvider];

[AWSServiceManager defaultServiceManager].defaultServiceConfiguration = configuration;
```

After that, I am trying to initialize a SimpleDB client likes this:

```
sdbClient = [[AmazonSimpleDBClient alloc] initWithAccessKey:[credentialsProvider accessKey] withSecretKey:[credentialsProvider secretKey]];
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Are you mixing version 1 and 2 of the AWS Mobile SDK for iOS? They are not designed to be used together, and you should consider migrating to the version 2 entirely.

The v2 SDK automatically calls `- refresh` on credentials providers when appropriate. Because you are not using `AWSSimpleDB`, `- refresh` has never been called, and that is why `accessKey` and `secretKey` return `nil`.

`AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider` generates AWS temporary credentials consisting of `accessKey`, `secretKey`, and `sessionKey`. `- initWithAccessKey:withSecretKey:` does not take temporary credentials, and even if you manually call `- refresh` on the credentials provider, `AmazonSimpleDBClient` does not function.

I recommend rewriting the app using `AWSSimpleDB` instead of `AmazonSimpleDBClient` in order to use Amazon Cognito Identity.